# What mobile affordances are planned for this sire?

Tags: feature-request, mobile, iphone

Are there plans for a mobile version of this site?

The usual version works OK, but a more compact version with fewer images would be nice.

Is this considered/ruled out/in the works?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can check out [StackMobile](http://stackmobile.com/beta/), or the iPhone app [Six to Eight](http://sixtoeightapp.com). Both are created by our talented http://stackapps.com members. However right now we only offer read-only API, so with these two apps you can only browse the questions and answers.